# How run specific csv file based on specific users using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

I have test plan like this:

`Thread group
         |---User parameter(user'scredentials mention there)
     |--Request body (same for the users)
     |----csv file1
     |-----csv file2`

Now if it is `users.name==joe`, this should execute `csvfile1` if it is `user.name==nmeon`, execute `csvfile2` through user parameter I got user name in the JMeter console.

How to write the script using IF controller/ bean shell If I use what would the script written for this?

Comment: `         |---User parameter(user'scredentials mention there)` is this CSV file or `User defined variables`

Comment: You can use this code `"${usernamevar}" == "joe'"` in the If controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have 2 options:

1. Change your file names to be `nmeon.csv` and `joe.csv` and use `${user.name}` in the CSV Data Set Config "Filename" section

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Variable]
2. Use 2 [If Controllers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) like:

   - If Controller, condition: `${user.name} == "joe"`

     - test logic specific for joe
   - If Controller, condition: `${user.name} == "nmeon"`

     - test logic specific for nmeon
3. Use [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) (the approach is similar to If Controllers)